# NameError: name 'Yes' is not defined when comparing input

Tags: python

I can't figure out why this is getting an error that states that 'Yes' is not specified.  What does that mean?  Why won't this work?  The `fuelEconomy` input statement works and the function works as well.  For some reason I can't get the `while` statement to accept the 'Yes' input to execute the function.

```
# This program is to calculate fueld economy
def main ():
    fuelEconomy = input ("Do you want to calculate your fuel economy? ")
    print (fuelEconomy)
    while fuelEconomy == Yes:

        Economy ()

    fuelEconomy = input ("Do you want to calculate another?")

#This function is the input and calculation for the program
def Economy ():
        mileage = int (input ("Input mileage "))
        gallons = int (input ("Input gallons used "))
        economy = mileage/gallons
        print ('Your economy is', economy, 'MPG') 

main ()
```

Comment: This is definitely not a good question title.  Please edit the question and change it.

Comment: Looks like it has been changed but I'll do better in the future.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be a string.

```
while fuelEconomy == 'Yes':
```

However your code still won't actually work, because that is now an infinite loop as the value of fuelEconomy cannot change within the loop. You probably meant for the next line to also be inside the loop.

Comment: Because if you put just `Yes`python thinks that you somewhere have defined a variable named Yes

Comment: So, going on with that infinite loop a bit....Wouldn't the code end when the user input 'no'?  My intent behind this is to execute the main.  Once the user inputs 'Yes' then the function will execute and end placing the user back at the fuelEconomy prompt again so that they can either do it again if they choose or input no at that prompt and end the program.  Again, this is my first programming class so forgive me if this is stupid or elemental but I'm just not picking up how this is an infinite loop.  Any and all wisdom is appreciated!

Comment: But what you describe won't happen, because the second input is not within the loop. The way it is now, it will just call Economy over and over again forever, and never proceed to the input. You need to indent that next line so that it is also within the loop.

Comment: As I said, indent the input line so it is at the same level as the Economy call.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks!  Just so that I understand properly, without it being indented the interpreter will read that as part of the main code right?  I guess I would have thought that once the code completes the function it would go to the next line of main code.  Clearly I'm wrong but I'm not sure I understand why.